# What kind of moth is this? Why does it have a stinger?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

[image: The moth died before I could photograph it]

Unfortunately, the moth died before I could photograph it.

The body length is approximately 2-3Inches. It was much bigger than the moths I usually see. And this is the first moth that I have seen which has a stinger. Does anyone know which moth this is?

This moth was found on Sep 16th in Bangalore, India. (Sorry, I missed this information before)

Comment: Welcome to the Biology Stack Shobana, please take a [tour] and visit the [help] for more information on this site and how it works. Please also edit your question with where you live in the world, as species present vary quite a bit depending on where you are. A large nearby city or a state, even country might be enough for us to get a good ID.

Comment: lots of things are unknown your location and the natur type is two of them.do you know for sure it is a stinger is an other unknown.

Comment: @trondhansen : I am guessing it is a stinger, I am not completely sure. It felt hard and sharp.

Comment: without knowing what country or region this is from, @shobanas it is hard to make any progress towards an ID

Answer (score 1):

Without information about the origin and/or better quality photos of this moth, it reminds me of and ***could be*** a member of the subfamily [Arctiinae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arctiinae).

What might look as a stinger, is part of its [gential apparatus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lepidoptera_genitalia) which is usually more or less retracted into the abdomen. Being not too familiar with moths, I guess it should be - depending on the sex - either the [ovipositor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ovipositor) or the [claspers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clasper).